# Java send mail - how to use "Send via"

Tags: email, jakarta-mail

We are sending mails from our local system.
We got our IPs white listed.
We have a scenario where we have to send email on behalf of somebody.
for ex: our email id is: support@mycompany.com
but we need to send email with a from address: john@abc.com

When we send with different from address, the receiving mail client displays "phishing" error.
One of the solution is to use "via" as dispayed in google link
https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=185812
[image]

We also want the message to be displayed like this in receivers inbox.
Any pointers in this will help us a lot.
thanks in advance.
Note: We are using localhost as the smtp.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Read about email headers. you can add email headers while creating the mail message at runtime.

    import javax.mail.*;
    import javax.mail.internet.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public void postMail( String recipients[ ], String subject, String message , String from) throws MessagingException
    {
        boolean debug = false;

         //Set the host smtp address
         Properties props = new Properties();
         props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.jcom.net");

        // create some properties and get the default Session
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        session.setDebug(debug);

        // create a message
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        // set the from and to address
        InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
        msg.setFrom(addressFrom);

        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[recipients.length]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++)
        {
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i]);
        }
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);


        // Optional : You can also set your custom headers in the Email if you Want
        msg.addHeader("MyHeaderName", "myHeaderValue");

        // Setting the Subject and Content Type
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setContent(message, "text/plain");
        Transport.send(msg);
    }


for further reading check this :
```

http://www.javacommerce.com/displaypage.jsp?name=javamail.sql&id=18274
http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html
@http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html

You can create aliases for the smtp server too.

Comment: Hi Shashwat, thanks for the information. Can you please let me know the actual header to set "via". I search and could not get the information from java mail api too. Thanks again.

Comment: public void postMail( String recipients[ ], String subject, String message , String from) throws MessagingException                                Here last argument is String from, just try to give your from address here and check i think it will work

Comment: Hi Shaswath, giving from address is making marking the message as spam or phishing message

Comment: You need to have the authentic domain for the mail servers as, if it not a registered and verified the mail will go to the spam.

Comment: I don't see where this question is answered. He asks for "how to send an mail "on behalf of"?" and your answer him how to relay a message which will be marked as phishing!